# How to spread component props inside passed node element?

Tags: reactjs

My question might be confusing but let me explain with an example here, let's say I have `Button` component and it has 5 different props like (type, href, appearance...) and if we want to do following:

```
<Button type='button' href='<a { ...buttonProps }>Test Link</a>'/>
```

Basically attach all Button props to `a` tag easily.

I found something similar over [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/850) but didn't get it. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is Button component?

Comment: hmm, what means, what is Button component ? I created Button component - it renders <button>. I am trying to build design system...

Comment: so do you want that button to render anchor tag instead of button tag in some condition?

Comment: Yes, and to apply every prop what has Button component but I didn't want to add anchor tag inside Button component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your button component and it should accept tag as property.

```
export default function Button({ Tag = "button", children, ...props }) {
  return <Tag {...props}>{children}</Tag>;
}
```

use button like this.

```
<Button>Test</Button>
<Button Tag="a" href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
  Test Link
</Button>
```

working codesandbox:

[image: Edit silent-worker-0j873]

Comment: Looks really good approach, one more question: Is it any simple solution how should I pass react-router-dom "Link" element? If I pass from Tag prop it renders <link> tag. I don't think that it is good idea to install react-router-dom package inside design system so if you have suggestions please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if I understand the question properly:

Hooks area:

```
const clickHandler = () => {
    top.location.href = 'http://localhost';
}
```

Then in the body

```js
<Button onClick={()=>clickHandler(e)}>My Button</Button>
```

Comment: No, I need to pass either 'a' tag or react-router Link component and want to apply every prop what Button has on 'a' or Link component